# ANDing on array of function

Tags: javascript

Given:

```
const a = () => true
const b = () => false

const t = [a, b]
```

How can I generate an additive AND:

`a() && b()`

In this case, it would return `false`.

Comment: What's wrong with what you currently wrote? `a() && b()`?

Comment: are you saying you want `t` to be a single true or false value depending on if all values are true or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reduce the array by using `true` as *startValue* and perform a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND) by using the result of the function call.

This approach keeps the value of the function calls.

```js
const a = () => true
const b = () => false

const t = [a, b]

console.log(t.reduce((r, f) => r && f(), true));
```

Approach with a stored value for the result and a short circuit.

```
const AND = array => {
        var result = true;
        array.every(fn => result = result && fn());
        return result;
    };
```

Comment: Oh, sorry for duplicating but I didn't see your answer before mine

Comment: With an array like `[() => false, 10000 more items]` this would make 10000 useless loops.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
const a = () => true
const b = () => false
    
const t = [a, b]

console.log(t.every(f => f()));
```

This will only produce a boolean value, so if you were intending to get a different result as if short circuiting you'll have to use a `reduce()` solution or other.

Comment: dv, not me, but it changes the value of the functions to `true` or `false`. actually the return value is a boolean, but it could be other value and this values changes by using `every`.

Comment: @NinaScholz `every()` checks truthiness of the return value, which is what `&&` will compare anyway, I think they should be functionally equivalent no?

Comment: Not the dv either. The result of `1 && 2` in JS is 2, and `0 && 2` would be 0. With your code the result of `[() => 1, () => 2]` would be `true`, and it should be `2`.

Comment: @OriDrori Ah I see now, forgot about that behavior in JS. Thanks, added that detail in my answer.

Comment: I downvoted because it won't work exactly as an && evaluation, which I presumed was the crux of the question. After looking it over the OP is unclear about what exactly they're looking for, so I would remove it at least if I could, but it's apparently "locked in", something I was unaware of happening ( kind of a stupid policy, I think ). You have my apologies.

Comment: @zfrisch Thanks for explaining, it's no problem. You were correct that it's a possible deficiency in my answer compared to Nina's solution.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, using `a() && b()` will work perfectly. If you want to use the `t` array, you can do it like this: `t[0]() && t[1]()`. However, if you want multiple inputs, I think it would be good to use an array function (`Array.prototype.reduce`):

```js
t.reduce((previous, item) => previous && item(), true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.find()` to get the 1st function with a falsy value. If none found, take the last function in the array, and if the array is empty use the fallback function that returns `undefined`. Invoke the function that you got.

```js
const fn = arr => (
  arr.find(f => !f()) || arr[arr.length - 1] || (() => undefined)
)()

console.log(fn([() => true, () => false])) // false
console.log(fn([() => 1, () => 2])) // 2
console.log(fn([() => 1, () => 0, () => 2])) // 0
console.log(fn([])) // undefined
```